# Override serialization

Tags: java, gwt, serialization

I am using GWT and my data transfer objects (those that get sent from server to the frontend using RPC) need to be either implement java.io.Serializable or com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable.  What I would like to do is some how extend/override one of these interfaces so that when GWT calls the serialization function (behind the scenes) it calls my method.  My method would first check that the class is safe to send and if so then call the serialization function or if not safe to send then throw an error.  Is this possible?  Where would I start?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to mess with serialization. If you want to make a check before sending data, extend your RPC service with a method to check your object, and raise an exception to inform the client.

Comment: I don't quite follow you.  I really only care about objects returned via RPC from the server.  For example I want to make sure an object from the datastore has any restricted info removed from it brfore being sent to the client when the client asked for info via an RPC call.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the documentation on serializable you will find the following:

> Classes that require special handling during the serialization and deserialization process must implement special methods **with these exact signatures**:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
    throws IOException
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
private void readObjectNoData()
    throws ObjectStreamException;
```

Maybe try implementing writeObject and readObject. Note that these methods are private and do not override anything, this is all handled through inspection a.f.a.i.k.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html